# System.IO.FileNotFoundException when running TCP Socket client tutorial in Windows Phone 8

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to run the [How to create and use a TCP socket client app for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) but get the following errors ...

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.Net.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.Net.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.Net.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.Net.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
```

I have the Simple IP services running on my dev computer and the phone is linked via USB when debugging. It does not suggest in the article what you should use for the IP address to reach the dev computer from the phone - I have tried,

```
192.168.1.66 // Dev computer address on lan
whitby       // Dev computer name
127.0.0.1    // Localhost, refers to dev computer or phone?
localhost    // ditto
```

I'm guessing as well, if the host was wrong I would get a nice error message - instead, nothing (i.e. empty string) is echoed back from `e.SocketError.ToString()`

I am using Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've figured it out. I was used to Windows Phone 7 programming and it seems that the  System libraries throw exceptions as a matter of course in Windows Phone 8 - the app continues to run.

The problem was that the firewall was blocking the Simple IP services ports. To get the to work you can temporarily disable the Windows Firewall:

- Type 'Firewall' at the Start Menu to get the 'Windows Firewall with Advanced Security' client
- Click 'Windows Firewall Properties'
- Under the 'Private Profile' tab, set the 'Firewall State' to 'Off' temporarily

Then connect using the IP of the dev computer e.g. 192.168.1.66 (not localhost, 127.0.0.1 etc.)